# JTextfield property change using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I use the following code for changing the properties of a JTextField. It worked properly. My problem is how to change the JTextField properties by passing parameters without using the default functions. For example if I want to change the JTextField LEFT property means using parameter (control name,left,100) like this. How do I change a JTextField property by passing parameters to the JTextField Property using the following code?

```
package textfield;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class textf implements ActionListener
{
    JTextField txt;
    JButton width;
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    //Font font = UIManager.getFont("txt.font");
    public textf()
    {
       frame=new JFrame();
       panel=new JPanel();
       txt=new JTextField(10);
       width=new JButton("width");
       width.setBounds(20, 200, 50, 40);

    panel.add(txt);
    panel.add(width);
    width.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(panel);



       // n.getContentPane().add(new textf());
        frame.setSize(440,310);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    txt.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
    txt.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.LEFT);
     txt.setSize(100,100);
      txt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 90));

       txt.putClientProperty("txt.sizeVariant", "small");

        txt.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans",Font.ITALIC,20));
        txt.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        txt.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new textf();

    }


}
```

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: Either I didn't understand your question, or the answer is already there: use setHorizontalAlignment().

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to set the position of the JTextField (if not please explain what you mean by 'LEFT' property)

```
tf.setBounds(LEFT,tf.getY(),tf.getWidth(),tf.getHeight());
```

Comment: (whatever the real question, -1 for the answer ;)  - never do manual positioning/sizing, that's the task of the LayoutManager

Comment: @kleopatra I strongly disagree. If there are more than a few elements on a pane, you're right. But if you just have to arrange two elements of known properties there is no need or use for the LayoutManager overhead. Also there are a lot of uses for manual positioning in graphical interactive programs (games for example) where you don't and can't use a LayoutManager properly.

Comment: naturally, everybody is free to waste his/her time in fighting a framework instead of using it as designed ;-)

Comment: Layout managers do more than just position a component. Even if games are an exception, this is not a game and so the suggestion should not have been made. The answer should be given in the context of the question. For a basic form you should not be using a null layout with setBounds().

Comment: @kleopatra Never say never. There always exists a situation, however rare, where some kind of manual tweaking becomes (regrettably) necessary. +1 from me.